# kibana no living connections with opendistro

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

i faced some issue where i need to setup the connection between kibana and elasticsearch.

curl http://elasticsearch:9200/ is working fine

**what i notice here when i add logstash configuration then this kibana wouldnt able to start and throw below error**

{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-10-03T03:18:47Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Request error, retrying\nGET https://elasticsearch:9200/_nodes?filter_path=nodes.*.version%2Cnodes.*.http.publish_address%2Cnodes.*.ip => write EPROTO 139866282088320:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:\n"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-10-03T03:18:47Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://elasticsearch:9200/"}
odfe-kibana   | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-10-03T03:18:47Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}

any idea ?

Comment: are you using opendistro elasticsearch and kibana?

Comment: yup, thanks for your reply...its resolved now

Comment: @zz10 I have the same problem. Can you describe what was the problem and how have you've solved it?

Comment: yaa..the main things here is for me i have to change the elasticsearch in docker-compose.yml configuration to add this conf *cluster.initial_master_nodes*